# Why did I keep receiving the same value for columns even though i already group by it? [SQLite]

Tags: sql, sqlite

this is my first question in StackOverflow.. hope someone can help.

why did I keep receiving the same value on 'Total Love Review' and 'Total Hate Review', even though I group by it by is_open?

here's my tables

**business**

| id | name | is_open | stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Business A | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | Business B | 0 | 3.8 |
| 3 | Business C | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | Business D | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | Business E | 0 | 3.2 |

**review**

| reviewId | business_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Love review |
| 2 | 1 | Love review |
| 3 | 1 | Love review |
| 4 | 2 | Hate review |
| 5 | 3 | Love review |
| 6 | 3 | Love review |
| 7 | 4 | Love review |
| 8 | 5 | Love review |

here's the query

```
select business.is_open
    ,(select count (review.text)
    from review
    where review.text like '%love%') as 'Total Love Review'
    ,(select count (review.text)
    from review
    where review.text like '%hate%') as 'Total Hate Review'
,avg(business.stars) as 'Avg Stars'
from business
left join review on business.id = review.business_id
group by is_open
```

here's the result

| is_open | Total Love Review | Total Hate Review | Avg Stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 1 | 3.5000 |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | 4.8333 |

expected results:

| is_open | Total Love Review | Total Hate Review | Avg Stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 3.5000 |
| 1 | 6 | 0 | 4.8333 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=971f3cb4f299568d4be77240e6c78178)*

Comment: (Edit) Please reserve images for things that *can't* be represented in text. I updated your 1st question to be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . i.e. Consist of 1) DDL + DML (Create table and insert statements) 2) Sample data 3) Expected results vs Actual

Comment: thank you for the correction, will do better next time

Comment: Sounds good.  Including all of the necessary info always makes it easier for others to assist you with questions.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why did I keep receiving the same value...

The subqueries are not grouped by is_open. As a result, the fields displayed in the table will be the same. Perhaps try something like this:

```
    Select business.is_open
      , review.review_text As Review
      , count(review.review_text) As ReviewCount
      , Avg(stars) As AvgStars
    FROM business
    LEFT JOIN review
    ON business.business_id = review.business_id
    GROUP BY is_open
      , review_text
```

Which would give result like:

```
_____________________________________________________
| is_open | Review | ReviewCount | AvgStars         |
|_________|________|________________________________|
|    0    | Hate   |    5        | 1.4              |
|_________|________|________________________________|
|    0    | Love   |    12       | 4.33333333333333 |
|_________|________|________________________________|
|    1    | Hate   |    9        | 1.44444444444444 |
|_________|________|________________________________|
|    1    | Love   |    19       | 4.42105263157895 |
_____________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you don't need subqueries here. Use a conditional SUM() to count the reviews by type.

```
 select b.is_open
     , sum( case when r.text like '%love%' then 1 else 0 end ) AS 'Total Love Review'
     , sum( case when r.text like '%hate%' then 1 else 0 end ) AS 'Total Hate Review'
     , avg(b.stars) as 'Avg Stars'
 from  business b
         left join review r on b.id = r.business_id
 group by b.is_open
```

**Results:**

> ```
> is_open | Total Love Review | Total Hate Review |       Avg Stars
> ------: | ----------------: | ----------------: | --------------:
>       0 |                 1 |                 1 |             3.5
>       1 |                 6 |                 0 | 4.8333333333333
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b71bb887a2b401ae12bf93774532e1c7)*